# Example for $a^k\equiv b^k$ and $k\equiv j$ but $a^j\not\equiv b^j\pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation

I need some help in the number theory please , Who can give me an example :
If $$a^k≡b^k \pmod{n}$$ and $$k≡j \pmod{n}$$ is not necessary to be $$a^j≡b^j \pmod{n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One counter example to you question is :
$$1^2\equiv 2^2\mod 3 ,\text{ and } 5\equiv 2\mod 3 \text{ and } 2^5 \equiv 2 \not \equiv 1^5\mod 3$$
Note that if we modify a little your statement, if$a,b$ are coprime then we have :
$$\left(a^k\equiv b^k\mod n\ \text{ and }\ \ k\equiv j\mod \varphi(n)\right)\Rightarrow a^j\equiv b^j\mod n $$
with $\varphi(n)$ is the [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)

Comment: Do you presume $\,(a,n) = 1 = (b,n)\,$ in your final equation?